# Mock to POST HTTP request get null pointer exception

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, mockito

I have this method

```
public HTTPResult post(String url, String requestBody) throws Exception {
    return HTTPPostPut(url, requestBody, HttpMethod.POST);
}

public HTTPResult HTTPPostPut(String url, String requestBody,HttpMethod httpMethod) throws Exception {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    headers.add("content-type","application/json");
    HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(requestBody,headers);

    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = this.restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, requestEntity, String.class);
        return new HTTPResult((String) response.getBody(), response.getStatusCode().value());
    } catch (ResourceAccessException var8) {
        String responseBody = var8.getCause().getMessage();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        return new HTTPResult(obj.getString("responseBody"), Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("statusCode")));
    }
}
```

Which I created for it mock and getting null pointer exception:

```
public void testPost() throws Exception{
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    headers.add("content-type","application/json");
    HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity("{blbl}",headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity("{blbl}",  HttpStatus.OK);

    RestTemplate mockRestTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);

    when(mockRestTemplate.exchange(baseUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class)).thenReturn(response);

    RestAPI api = new RestAPI(mockRestTemplate);

    HTTPResult res = null;
    try {
        res = api.post(baseUrl,"{blbl}");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    assertEquals(res.getResponseBody(), "{blbl}");
    assertEquals(res.getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.OK.value());
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception when calling:

```
res = api.post(baseUrl,"{blbl}");
```

This is because the response is null.

Comment: use argument matcher as the instance being passed to the mocked dependency is different to what is passed when invoked so it will return null as they do not match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an argument matcher when arranging the mock as the instance being passed to the mocked dependency is different to what is passed when the test is exercised.

This will cause the mock to return null response as expected instances do not match

Refactor the test

```
public void testPost() throws Exception {
    //Arrange
    String expected = "{blbl}";
    ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity(expected,  HttpStatus.OK);    

    RestTemplate mockRestTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);

    when(mockRestTemplate.exchange(eq(baseUrl), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(String.class)))
        .thenReturn(response);

    RestAPI api = new RestAPI(mockRestTemplate);

    //Act
    HTTPResult res = api.post(baseUrl, expected);

    //Assert
    assertEquals(res.getResponseBody(), expected);
    assertEquals(res.getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.OK.value());
}
```

Note the use of the `any(HttpEntity.class)` matcher which will allow the passed `HttpEntity` to be matched when invoked.

Since the use of argument matches is none or all, the `eq()` matcher is used for the remaining constant arguments.